# Sometimes cannot connect to HTTP server on Windows (the target machine actively refused the connection)

Tags: c++, windows, http

I'm attempting to run some mock tests for a C++ library on Windows. This involves spinning up an HTTP server (https://gitlab.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server) so that the library can make some requests to it on `localhost:8080`.

Most of the time this works OK, but I'm running into some confusing issues at the OS level. If I run the test suite application too soon after a previous run, I get errors stating that the HTTP connections could not be made to the server, because "the target machine actively refused it". This causes a few issues on our CI server, as we run 32-bit tests followed by 64-bit tests, and some of the time the second batch of tests will fail because of these connection rejections. If I wait a bit between runs then the connections usually work again (though not always).

It should be noted that the HTTP server is started up at the beginning of each individual test, and torn down after. It is not persistent between tests or between process runs, so there should be no dangling connections or anything like that. This is what leads me to believe this is an issue at the OS level.

Is there any good reason why this might be happening? It's quite difficult for me to debug because I'm not even really sure what the problem is - maybe Windows is not allowing port `8080` to be re-used until after a certain timeout?

Comment: Windows has no problems. Hundreds of thousands of web sites (if not millions) use Windows. Most likely your server is down

Comment: Maybe your clients are not closing the connection to server after use. Or maybe your server cannot take too much load or maybe your server refuses connection due to some incompatibility (TCP handshake?).

Comment: @kiner_shah The first point shouldn't be an issue since the server is created on a per-test basis within the test suite program, and is shut down after each test. The second and third also shouldn't be issues since the test runs themselves work perfectly fine under normal circumstances - it's just if the test suite executable is run too soon after a previous run, the connections fail.

Comment: `This involves spinning up an HTTP server` and all web servers need time to warm up, fill caches and buffers, initialize pipelines. That time appears as a response delay in the first request or requests. If your test makes 10-100 concurrent calls at once, all of them will have to work with cold caches and buffers, and all will pay the warmup penalty. That's why all high-traffic sites use warmup scripts, why adding a web server to traffic isn't as easy as making a config change to a load balancer

Comment: Cooldown is *also* an issue - depending on the server, it may take time to shutdown gracefully and cleanup any temporary files, caches, close database connections, release OS handles. `It is not persistent between tests` that makes things worse, not better. It means every test has to pay the warmup tax. That's why people often use IIS instead of IIS Express while debugging web apps - you don't have to wait for the web server to start when you start debugging